# How to change delimiter in date?

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, windows-server-2008

I got error when I tried send date from server because it had had a next form:

```
2013/02/21
```

When I send date from client it is sending without problem because it has next form:

```
2013-02-21
```

I need to change delimiter in server properties or in the code but I don't know how.

Comment: Don't send it as a string - send it as a datetime if possible.

Comment: it doesn't posible. Because if i send it as date year in the end.

Comment: I don't think you understand how datetimes are stored. It doesn't matter what it looks like when you inspect it, I expect that will call `ToString()` on it, in your current culture. How it looks when inspecting it does not represent how it's actually stored "behind the scenes". If you have a datetime in code, and you sent it as a datetime, and the server expects a datetime, you won't have any issues. Anywhere this a datetime is sent as a string and then re-interpretted as a dateime at the other end makes no sense, and is prone to errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending date using `ToString` then you can specify the format:

```
string str  = yourDateObject.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```